# How can I set a QWidget to use an entire row in a QTreeview?

Tags: qt, pyside, qtreeview

I need a QWidget to use (occupy, fill) an entire row in a QTreeview with several columns, but I can't find any clues on how to do such thing neither in the docs or the web. I guess this is not a super strange scenario, so it should be rather easy(?). I hope so.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Btw, the idea behind this is to mark rows as "deleted" instead of just removing them from the view. I want the original content of the row cells to stay where it was before the deletion, obscure the row and show a semi-translucent label or image on top of the entire row saying "CONTENT DELETED" or something like that.

Comment: How does that widget use the the row from QTreeView?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I messed up the words. I want the widget to be displayed all over the row, but I can only use setWidgetIndex on a cell. So I'm only able to display the widget over one cell. Sorry if I'm not being completely clear, English's not my natural language :/

Comment: Try to attach the picture with UI design you want.

Comment: You mean with a stylesheet? Didn't know that could be done. I'll give it a try tomorrow (it's 1 am here). Thanks!

Comment: png or gif or jpeg with picture.

Comment: Did you try [`QTreeView::setFirstColumnSpanned`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#setFirstColumnSpanned)?

Comment: @AlexanderVX, I tried with the stylesheet, but I need the image to be in the horizontal center of the row. I tried using QTreeView::item, but that draws the image over each cell instead of drawing it once. I also tried using ::branch, but didn't work at all (the image was not drawn). Am I missing something?

Comment: @thuga: The problem with that function is that I want the original content of the cells to be still visible when I put my widget/image on top of the row. `QTreeView::setFirstColumnSpanned` would mess all the data displayed in the cells.

Comment: @GuillermoAres, nothing comes to mind except overriding the draw event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847538/draw-focus-for-row-in-qtreeview You will need to override the pain event for row delegate for tree view: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow QTreeView::setItemDelegate can be used for that.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yeah, I don't see any other way :/. I'll try it out on Monday and come back to you when it's working. Thanks a lot!